# Is it a good practice to call the Salesforce apis every one minute?

Tags: rest-api, integration

We are considering various ways to integrate salesforce with a client's erp. The idea is that the accounts that are created from Salesforce are also created in the ERP. One proposal would be that, from the ERP, Salesforce be consulted every minute if there are new records, and if there are, insert them into the ERP. The idea is to do it with Standard REST API. Have you ever worked this way? What advantages/disadvantages could it have?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration decision guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration).

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the worst of the available options; you're using too many API calls, and inefficiently at that. You might consider subscribing to the CDC ([Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm)) channel for the object, which provides a near-real-time stream of record updates to your ERP. You also end up using far fewer API calls per day this way, even in a very busy org.

Alternatively, you might use the [sObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) and [sObject Get Deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm) REST methods (also available in SOAP if you prefer), which allows you to also know if there's *in-flight*; you'll know what time you need to use for your next replication window. This works well with the [Retrieve Multiple Records with Fewer Round-Trips](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm) method, that allows you to retrieve 2,000 records at once without a query. This API is recommended to be used in 5 minute intervals, though, which should suffice for most use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.